# Why can't I compare SeqRecord (from the Biopython Module)?

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython

So basically I have a list of sequences that I parsed in from SeqIO. I'm trying to filter them by their name. So if the list of sequences has duplicates, it would only take the first one. I've encountered the error below:

"SeqRecord comparison is deliberately not implemented. Explicitly compare the attributes of interest."

```
FilterDuplicates = []
FilteredNames = []

for i in Sequences:
    if i.name not in FilteredNames:
        #Append SeqRecord Object to list
        FilterDuplicates.append(i)
        #Append the name to the list of names
        FilteredNames.append(i.name)
```

Comment: It seems to me that your code is comparing "the attributes of interest". Is the above code generating the error message you mention, or is it your corrected code?

Comment: Do you have a list of sequences or a list of SeqRecord ? Or something else ? We need the input list to try to test your code.